# Tagging a revision with a file-specified commit message in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to tag a revision in Mercurial using a file for the message rather than just the `-m` argument for specifying a message?

Comment: I ended up copying the file to the clipboard, and pasting it into the TortoiseHg commit message (not really what I had in mind...but it worked) 

Still I'd like to find out how to add the message through a file.

Answer (score 2):

On *nix or Cygwin, you can use the backtick trick:

```
bash-4.1$ hg init test
bash-4.1$ cd test
bash-4.1$ echo something > a
bash-4.1$ hg ci -A -m "First commit."
adding a
bash-4.1$ echo "Custom tag message" > msg.txt
bash-4.1$ hg tag mytag -m "`cat msg.txt`"          # tag message from file
bash-4.1$ hg tags
tip                                1:1b6138117d00
mytag                              0:679f354e7ec1
bash-4.1$ hg log
changeset:   1:1b6138117d00
tag:         tip
user:        gavin
date:        Tue Mar 29 21:43:55 2011 -0500
summary:     Custom tag message

changeset:   0:679f354e7ec1
tag:         mytag
user:        gavin
date:        Tue Mar 29 21:43:22 2011 -0500
summary:     First commit.
```

Comment: The [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) tools for Windows (which are installed by default) are quite capable and good. I use them in conjunction with CLI via `cmd.exe` on Windows.

Comment: @bentsai, I guess I meant within CLI options, which it seems the OP is using.  I often find I want to move the uncommitted files, or otherwise loop against `hg st`, for example, that would be a pain in the `.BAT`, so to speak :)

Comment: This doesn't look like tagging to me...unless I'm missing something, like you secretly modified the .hgtags file, before the commit.

Comment: @leeand00, very sorry!  I misread the question quite wrongly.  Updated my answer.  I don't know of a reasonable way to do this in native Windows.

Answer (score 1):

That somewhat depends on if you are just trying to have a large message as the argument. If that is your goal, then you can just use backticks. Ie:

```
hg commit -m "`cat myfiletxt`"
```

You would have to be careful to make sure there are no doublequotes in that file though! There are quite a few gotchas sitting there, but that should get you started at least... Though it's worth mentioning, that requires you to be in a *nix shell of some sort.

Now if you meant to specify a file as a pointer, I do not believe there is currently a method to say 'see (file) for details' presently. Though you could just use that as your commit message. :)

Comment: Yeah I suppose there might be a way to do this using the type command in cmd (maybe...).

Comment: This also doesn't look like the tagging command to me (unless like @harpo you're modifying the .hgtags file yourself before the commit).

Comment: The taggin command works roughly the same as the commit command does. But it appears the gent above me has answered the question in detail. :-)